# how to do multiple get with multiple databases in Redis

Tags: redis

In redis, is it possible to do MGET on multiple databases?

something like:

```
select 1
set a hello
select 2
set b world

mget db1:a db2:b
```

Answer (score 0):

Redis does not provide a way to associate names with the different databases, so you will have to keep track of what data goes where yourself. See [here](http://rediscookbook.org/multiple_databases.html)

So , what you want to do is not possible.
[image]

Because, SELECT command selects the database i.e. index of database and we can't SELECT two databases and only after SELECTing indices , we can run the commands.

Comment: I've checked what you post above, but I don't think it associats with your conclusion. The tip only tell us there is no link between db id and db name.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on that, because I've tried these hours ago. Sorry didn't post at the first time. But, I'm looking for a possible solution to this demand, perhaps with lua scripts or something else I don't know.

Comment: I'm asking this because I haven't found documents about detail mechanisms on databases in redis other than "select x". So, maybe I'm looking for an answer. Is databases absolutly isolated from each other in redis like Databases in mysql, or just like tables which can have some relationships with each other?